# Where does Phabricator store locales?

Tags: phabricator

I'd like to rename phabricator's applications, such as Manifest, Phriction etc. 
How can I do it? where can I find the values to edit? I have no idea where to check.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported, and we never plan to let you rename applications. If you're set on doing this, you'll have to fork the codebase.

Comment: Hi, Evan! Thank you for the answer!
I am going to use phabricator to work on multiple projects, so it would be better for me to change everything to fit my needs, therefore yes, I will fork the codebase. Anyway, where to find the locales in case I will?

Answer (score 0):

With the latest update it is possible to rename the applications!